# What is the default Curve behavior for PageView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

The `PageController` of a `PageView` has a function `animateToPage` which allows to define the curve effect during page swipe.

```
Future<void> animateToPage(
    int page, {
    @required Duration duration,
    @required Curve curve,
  })
```

I need to match it's behavior with that of the default swipe transition of PageView.

Any help?

Comment: page swipe from iOS style ?

Comment: it does not use `Curve` for swipes: it uses [physics](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView/physics.html) property - for more see `packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_view.dart` source file

Comment: and more or less it follows `SpringSimulation`

Comment: Thanks @pskink, my problem is that I am not able to relate the Physics behavior with the Curves animation. However, Curves.ease as suggested by Rubens does seem to match with the default behavior of PageView scroll.

Comment: no it is not - see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves-class.html - i would say more realistic is `decelerate` or `easeOut*`

Comment: and how are you comparing these two effects with that of the PageView?

Comment: how? this is more or less how [SpringSimulation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/physics/SpringSimulation-class.html) works

Comment: I will have to do further research before concluding. But thanks a lot for your help @pskink

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @pskink in the comments, the default `PageView` transition animation relies on the physics applied by the user's gesture. Depending on the user's swipe, it's then translated to the page's transition animation.

On the other hand, `PageController`'s `animateToPage` relies on the duration set and curve. To emulate a smooth swipe, you can use [`Curves.ease`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves/ease-constant.html) as previously mentioned.